# Python, Linked list: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_next'

Tags: python-3.x, oop, exception, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to do an implementation of a simple linked list but I keep getting this exception: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_next'.
here is my code:

```
           class Lista:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.len_l = 0

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.len_l:
            return "::EMPTY::"
        lista_c = ""
        next_node = self.root
        while next_node:
            if next_node.get_next():
                if type(next_node.get_datos()) != str:
                    lista_c += "%s -> "%(next_node.get_datos())
                else:
                    lista_c += "'%s' -> "%(next_node.get_datos())
            else:
                if type(next_node.get_datos()) != str:
                    lista_c += " %s"%(next_node.get_datos())
                else:
                    lista_c += " '%s'"%(next_node.get_datos())

            next_node = next_node.get_next()
        return lista_c

    def add(self, dato):
        self.root = nodo(dato,self.root)
        self.len_l += 1

    def find(self,dato):
        if not self.len_l:
            raise LSLexception("empty list")
        this_node = self.root
        while this_node.get_next():
            if dato == this_node.get_datos():
                return this_node
            this_node = this_node.get_next()
        return -1

    def Valid_pos(self,pos):
        if self.len_l == 0:
            raise LSLexception("empty list")
        if pos not in range(0,self.len_l):
            raise LSLexception("data overflow")

    def remove(self,dato):
        if not self.len_l:
            raise LSLexception("empty list")
        if self.root.get_datos() == dato:
            self.root = self.root.get_next()
        previous_node = self.root
        this_node = previous_node.get_next()
        while this_node.get_next():
            if this_node.get_datos() == dato:
                previous_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())
                return this_node 
            else:
                previous_node = this_node
                this_node = previous_node.get_next()
        return -1
```

The problem occurs in the function remove in this line `while this_node.get_next():` but I'm using that same line in the function "find" an I. Works fine, any ideas? Is for college so there are some things I can't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to put parentheses when you try to call `get_next`, so some of the node variables are assigned to a function instead of a node.

Like `this_node = previous_node.get_next` in `def remove(self, dato)`, you might want to change that to 
`this_node = previous_node.get_next()`

Also, `set_next` in `previous_node.set_next = this_node.get_next` also looks like a function to me. You might want to change that too.